# startup issue: minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. grub>

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

I'm really noobe. I've tried fixing issue by googling problem, but can't get this fixed. I tried starting up with USB stick, and to fix with Boot-repair. I get the message: GPT detected, please create BIOS-boot partition.  I've tried some more googling, but can't seem to fix this. created a bootinfo summary : http://paste2.org/E5JUNDkD   I hope someone can help me fix this.

Thank you, Sven

Comment: What were you doing up to this point?

Comment: I was starting a game on steam, and the computer just restarted.... leaving me with this problem.

Comment: Do you want to convert your Ubuntu from UEFI-mode to legacy-mode? Then you need to create BIOS-boot-partition (1MB, unformatted, BIOS-boot-flag) on `sdd`because the drive has GPT.

Comment: I`m really noobe, so I have to say... whatever it takes to make ubuntu start up again. But I don`t know how to create a BIOS-boot-flag...?

Comment: I`ve googled it, I`ll have a try....

Comment: Im trying to fix my boot, using info on this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CreateBootPartitionAfterInstall   but it seems as if my boot flag ison a fat32 partition. is that causing problems for me?

Comment: at the point where Im suppose to copy /boot files, I get: cp: cannot stat `/mnt/main/boot/*` no such file or directory

Comment: Its fixed!!!! All thanks to boot-repair. :-)